# How to use dependentRequired with relative reference in JSON schema

Tags: json, json.net, jsonschema

I have below JSON schema in my app, and i am using `NewtonSoft JSON schema validation` library to validate user JSON against my schema.

The rules that i need to set are -

1. if user sets `property2` in the JSON then `property3` should also exist and `subProperty2` should also exist underneath `property3`.
2. if user does not set `property2` then `property3` is not required.

I used `dependentRequired` for this with relative reference using `period(.)` but that did not work with `NewtonSoft` package. I tried in 2 different ways, both without expected result.

```json
{
  "type": "object",
  "additionalProperties": false,
  "properties": {
    "property1": {
      ...
    },
    "property2": {
      ...
    },
    "property3": {
      "type": "object",
      "additionalProperties": false,
      "properties": {
        "subProperty1": {
          ...
        },
        "subProperty2": {
          ...
        },
      }
    }
  },
   "required": [
    "property1"
  ]
}
```

//try 1

```json
  "dependentRequired": {
    "property2": [ "property3.subProperty2" ]
  },
```

//try 2

```json
  "dependentRequired": {
    "property2": {
      "required": [ "property3" ],
      "property3": {
        "required": [ "subProperty2" ]
      }
    }
  }
```

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dot notation used in the first try is not supported in JSON Schema.

The second try is the right idea, but since you are using a schema, you need to use `dependentSchemas` instead of `dependentRequired`. Also, you are missing the `properties` keyword to make that a valid schema.

```json
  "dependentSchemas": {
    "property2": {
      "required": [ "property3" ],
      "properties": {
        "property3": {
          "required": [ "subProperty2" ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
```